# Expression must have a constant value : IAR R8C and M16

Tags: macros, return, iar

I am trying to compile the below code in IAR and I get the below error 
"Expression must have a const value" . But the same code compiles in GCC. Can anyone please point me out what is wrong in this code. Note: It is a legacy code.

Below is my code

```
/*Structure*/
typedef struct KEY_VALUE
{
    uint32_t key;
    void * value_1;
    void * value_2;
    uint16_t publish;
    uint16_t attributes;
}KEY_VALUE_STRUCT; 

/*Macro Assignment*/
#define CTESTCODE_1 ((void*)GetCount)
#define CTESTCODE_2 ((void*)0)


/*Function*/
uint32  GetCount(void)
{
    /*Get relay counts returns constant value*/
    return ((uint32)GetRelayCount());
}

/*Value*/
KEY_VALUE_STRUCT RelayCount[] = {
  {100,    CTESTCODE_2 ,  CTESTCODE_1 ,    TRUE, 0 }}
```

I want to use the return value of that function in an array. Please help me out in solving this .
Thanks!

Comment: *"I am trying to assign the constant value returned from a function to a macro"* But you are not even calling the function `GetCount` in `((void*)GetCount)`. You are simply returning the address of the function `GetCount` and converting it's type `uint32 (*)(void)` to `void*`. **Please check that you are showing correct code.** That aside, you cannot use function call return values to initialize variables with static storage duration in standard C. It's simply illegal. Some compilers might do it as an extension, but I doubt that too.

Comment: "I am trying to assign the constant value returned from a function to a macro" which was wrong. My code is what I intend to do which is assigning the address of the function to the pointer in structure. This is a legacy code which I am trying to compile in IAR

Comment: Are you sure that on your system data pointers and function pointers are the same size and convertible between each other? C doesn't guarantee that, but many compilers allow that because they are often the same size (32 bit ARM for example).

Comment: I am not really sure about it . I am using IAR compiler nd 64 bit Windows machine And my controller is R8C.

Comment: You should check the IAR manual about casting between pointers. My old IAR for ARM compiler manual says *"Casting a data pointer to a function pointer and vice versa is illegal"*. So it's not allowed for me, even when sizes are the same. I also checked the C standard and it doesn't seem to allow it either: function pointers can only be converted to other function pointers.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, My IAR manual says it as illegal as well. If its not allowed in C , I doubt why its compiling in GCC without even any warning . As you said earlier is it because of same size?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with R8C to know for sure. But many old compilers like GCC have been very forgiving in some aspects of C standard, so I guess it was possible because of the matching sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. Macros are evaluated before the code is even compiled by the preprocessor.
They **can** take variable if they represent constant expression but they cannot hold a variable.

There might be a way (I'd have to think about that) of hacking macro based function that does what you want to do. But you'd end up with very dangerous and hard to maintain code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But what I observed is this code compiles in Ubuntu . I am using GCC. But it does not in IAR . I am using Renesas R8C2A.

Comment: No problem, I think I've misunderstood what you are trying to do in the original post. Maybe it's toolchain specific problem? I've never compiled anything for R8C2A nor used IAR workbench.
Is their toolchain gcc based?

Comment: I think its a toolchain specific. IAR is using the  toolchain that comes with  product package supports a specific microcontroller.